# apache2.4 , where to setup mod_ssl, dont see any mod_ssl.so file

Tags: apache

Problem is the plain vanila apache is working, the moment I say sslEngine ON
it gives error, I am not able to find where any ssl setup is?
it does not create any log as well..

How this ssl setup is done? will copying a mod_ssl.so file from outside will work?

Apache version : 2.4.29

Os is RHEL 6.7

Comment: I dont see any mod_ssl.so under module folder..

Comment: Please edit the question and include some information about your operating system and the exact Apache distribution you are trying to configure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of research, I found below command which can help you show the actual issue while restarting. when I ran this it told me that .csr which I was using were wrong. I could not get this when I normally started the Apache but this command helped.

replace below with location where apache is installed and conf file is located, this will print the error ( if any).

`/xxx/app/xxx/apache22/0/bin/apachectl_worker -DSSL -k start -f` `/xxx/app/xxx/apache22/0/conf/xxx.conf`

Answer (score 0):

If this [Red Hat documentation](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/445713) is not wrong the RHEL 6.x releases include Apache/2.2. Since you have Apache/2.4 I'd say you probably have an unofficial binary. Such binaries could of course have been installed in any conceivable way so this answer can easily be wrong. Yet making the hopefully safe assumption that you're still using the package manager and you just switched to a third-party repository you can try this:

```
yum install mod_ssl
```

Then tweak `/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf` to your liking and restart the service:

```
service httpd graceful
```

Comment: Thanks much.. sad part is.. we have three box and it working on 2 boxes.. eventhoug we dont have any ssl there also.. :(